# Getting single level of files in a UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to iterate through the files in the "My Documents" folder, inside a UWP app.  The issue that I have is that this code:

```
var files = await KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFilesAsync(
            Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);

foreach (StorageFile f in files)
{
```

Drills into every folder recursively to find the files, but I don't want this: I want to get every file in the top level folder initially, and then list the sub folders and their contents; so the output would be more of a tree:

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
Folder1
    SubFolder
        Filen.txt
```

So, I either need to be able to restrict the above code to only look in the current folder (and simply call it recursively), or to be able to categorise the `files` collection by their path.  The reason that I don't seem to be able to do the latter is that f.path returns the fully qualified path (I realise that I could probably make some calls to determine exactly where it is, and split the string to get the location, but it feels like I'm reinventing a wheel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `GetFilesAsync()` method with no arguments. It will just return the top level files. But you have to order them by yourself (should not be a problem).